How to remove year and month in blogger URL
I want to remove year and month in the following link:
https://ana-post.blogspot.com/2024/08/strategies-for-finding-low-competition.html
I tried to put js code in the head area it works but a delaying occured while redirecting from original link to 404 to new link.

In Blogger, the default URL structure includes the date by design, and there isn't a way to completely remove the year and month from post URLs through the settings or by code
